# Importing numbers form a text file with a semicolon separator

Tags: import

I have a list of numbers separated by semicolon in text file and I would like to import the data and work with them. If I use

```
data = ReadList["file",Word,WordSeparators -> ";"] /. Word -> Number
```

it gives me word or string instead of number.
What can I do?

Comment: `ToExpression@ ReadList["file",Word,WordSeparators -> ";"] `?

Comment: or `ReadList["file", "Number",  "RecordSeparators" -> {";"}]`?

Comment: `ImportString[ StringReplace[Import[ file  , "Text"]  ,   ";" -> ","] , "CSV"]` maybe.   (also caution `ToExpression` wont work if any of the numbers are in E exponent form )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file = StringToStream["1;2;3;4.5;5.5;6.5"];
ReadList[file, Number, RecordSeparators -> {";"}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5}

Answer (score 0):

Your data file (like mine) probably has multiple lines, so using RecordSeparators -> {";"} will destroy the structure.
ToExpression is slow but more forgiving (e.g. allows trailing spaces).
Using Import is also very slow.

As you typically know the format of your data you can ReadList and call out the format treating the semicolon as a character:

```
file = StringToStream["1.1;+2;\n3;-4;\n5.5;   6;"];
ReadList[file, {Number, Character, Number, Character}][[;; , ;; ;; 2]]

{{1.1, 2}, {3, -4}, {5.5, 6}}
```

If you have n columns you may want to use

```
Flatten@Table[{Number, Character}, n]
```

or equally

```
Table[Unevaluated@Sequence[Number, Character], n]
```